# Create Dictionary using List

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to create a Dictionary with the following data:

```
ListA = ['Name', 'Age', 'Gender']
ListB = ['Alex', '22', 'Male']
        ['Kelly','21', 'Female']
```

ListB comes from FileB and looks like this:

`Alex 22 Male,Kelly 21 Female` (values tab separated, group comma separated)

Expected output:

```
{'Name' : 'Alex', 'Age' : '22', 'Gender' : 'Male',
 'Name' : 'Kelly', 'Age': '21', 'Gender' : 'Female'
}
```

I tried the following code:

```
fileB = glob.glob(filename + '.txt')
dfun = {}
ListB = []
for f in fileB:
    Lines = open(f, 'r').read().split(',')
    for i in Lines:
        Lines2 = i.split('\t')
        ListB.append(Lines2)
print(ListB)   # this gives me ListB in the format above. 

for i in ListB:
    List1 = ['Name', 'Age', 'Gender']
    List2 = i
    zip1 = zip(List1,i)
    zip2 = dict(zip1)
    dfun.update(zip2)
    print(dfun)
```

This code is only giving output as:

```
{'Name' : 'Kelly', 'Age': '21', 'Gender' : 'Female'}
```

Answer (score 5):

Your desired output is an invalid dictionary, as dictionaries cannot contain duplicate keys, however, you can use a list comprehension and store your dictionary values as elements in a list:

```
ListA = ['Name', 'Age', 'Gender']
ListB = [['Alex', '22', 'Male'], ['Kelly','21', 'Female']]
result = [dict(zip(ListA, i)) for i in ListB]
```

Output:

```
[{'Name': 'Alex', 'Age': '22', 'Gender': 'Male'}, {'Name': 'Kelly', 'Age': '21', 'Gender': 'Female'}]
```

Edit:

```
result = {a:[k[i] for k in ListB] for i, a in enumerate(ListA)}
```

Output:

```
{'Name': ['Alex', 'Kelly'], 'Age': ['22', '21'], 'Gender': ['Male', 'Female']}
```

Comment: Thank you Ajax, you are correct. This output is list so dictionary functions will not work here. so i cant do something like result['Name'] to get both the names. Is there a way to make a dictionary using just list B?

Comment: @HashCode Please see my recent edit, as I added a solution that forms a single dictionary result. Now you will be able to lookup desired header values and obtain results from all the lists in `ListB`.

Comment: perfect!! Thanks Ajax, this is helpful